# Symfony4 , Raw HTML and CSS using TWIG

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig, symfony4

I am trying to run a free front-end template on my Symfony4 project, I changed the index.html (of the template) to index.html.php so it can be supported by the the PHP engine of Symfony. But it still showing normal text without any style or img. I am not sure if it is a path problem or rendering issue.
In my index.html.php, I want to refer to my assets directory (which contains the img,css,...etc) which is situated on the same  level as my index.html.php, here are the full paths of the subject files and directories:

```
myproject/src/Resources/views/test/freeTemplateName/template/index.html.php
myproject/src/Resources/views/test/freeTemplateName/template/assets/.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should not have your assets in the `src` folder, but in the folder `public`. So for example you could put your css in `public/css/myfile.css`. Then refer to that file in your index.html.php like you normally would in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: I think you should do this when running the project using _php -S localhost:somePort -t public_ , but I am using _bin/console server:run _ isn't it ?

Comment: That should not have anything to do with it. Your assets need to be publicly accessible so any user's browser can read those files. The only folder which is accessible like this is your folder `public`.

Comment: Oh yeah I see. Now I understand it well and It worked !!!! Yes it worked!! Very big thanks